# exercise 18-8 python crash course - Can't loop

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to loop through the toppings but the code doesn't work.

models:

```
from django.db import models

class Pizza(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Toppings(models.Model):

pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'toppings'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'pizzas'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('pizzas/', views.pizzas, name='pizzas'),
    path('pizzas/<int:toppings_id>/', views.toppings, name='toppings')
]
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Pizza
from .models import Toppings

def index(request):
return render(request, 'pizzas/index.html')

def pizzas(request):

pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
context = {'pizzas': pizzas}
return render(request, 'pizzas/pizzas.html', context)


def toppings(request, toppings_id):

toppings = Toppings.objects.get(id=toppings_id)
context = {'toppings': toppings}
return render(request, 'pizzas/toppings.html', context)
```

toppings.html:

```
{% extends 'pizzas/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>Pizzas: {{ pizza }}</p>
<p>Toppings:</p>
<ul>
{% for topping in toppings %}
  <li>
      <p>{{ topping }}</p>
  </li>
{% empty %}
  <li>There are no toppings</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

pizzas.html:

```
{% extends 'pizzas/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>Pizzas</p>

<ul>
{% for pizza in pizzas %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url 'pizzas:toppings' pizza.id %}">{{ pizza }}</a>
  </li>
{% empty %}
  <li>
    No pizzas yet duh
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

The problem is in toppings.html on the for loop, and maybe something wrong with the toppings views too.

Comment: What does _the code doesn't work_ mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
toppings = Toppings.objects.get(id=toppings_id)
context = {'toppings': toppings}
```

you have single record because of using [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get). You can't loop over single object. Please, read the docs about methods usage.
If you want to list all toppings, then remove `toppings_id` from url and view, and use `all()` instead:

```
Toppings.objects.all()
```

You can look forward and check this [example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example) of how to create a view that allows to get single record by ID and list all records list.

Comment: I removed `toppings_id` but my code doesn't work either way now i get an error `NoReverseMatch at /pizzas/
Reverse for 'toppings' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['toppings/$']`
my code on views looks like this 
   `def toppings(request):
    toppings = Toppings.objects.all()
    context = {'toppings': toppings}
    return render(request, 'pizzas/toppings.html', context)`
my `toppings.html` is the same than above on the post

I tried making this `path('toppings/', views.toppings, name='toppings')` but i still get the error of No reverseMatch
I can't get this work